# how to increase size of div with hidden overflow (not using width/height)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that auto slides through a set of pictures. I want to increase its size without ruining the slideshow. I filled it with random pics for demonstration. First I tried the normal method of adjusting height and width properties but that runs into the hidden overflow which I wan't to avoid?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
  <style>
 body {
  margin: 10%;
   margin-left:20%;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 265px;
 
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10000%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 750ms ease;
  left: 0;
}
#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
 
  float: left;
}
#slider ul li img{
  width: 500px;
  height: 265px;
}
 
#slider #prev, #slider #next {
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 150ms ease;
}
#slider #prev:hover, #slider #next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 0;
}
#slider #prev {
  left: 10px;
}
#slider #next {
  right: 10px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider">
    <ul id="slideWrap"> 
      <li><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GgceYGYr2pk/YPCQp8loxqI/AAAAAAAACXU/Y795AFD-cN8PMV0V2__z2n1B3KFagE8qgCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pl0VR_xS5Cw/YPCQp1scezI/AAAAAAAACXc/oB9xc6k8RuY5rPksMSy01f3iUn8zSIFzwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dt6CL2fiBq0/YPCQp0zmK6I/AAAAAAAACXY/0PevDL7pvx87mefb4oCnO613N1UitdicQCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T_V-s57aVDo/YPCQrWayswI/AAAAAAAACXg/h1ifJGnBuXovvBdGDNvmhg-DXIVK4Xw9QCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TNT1a5M1v3o/YPCQrWmn_fI/AAAAAAAACXk/p8nx_OB2R6Aw172WIv5vuB8jF-qWDsHlwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/5.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="prev" href="#">&#8810;</a>
    <a id="next" href="#">&#8811;</a>
  </div>


  <script>
    var responsiveSlider = function() {

var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var sliderWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
var slideList = document.getElementById("slideWrap");
var count = 1;
var items = slideList.querySelectorAll("li").length;
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
var next = document.getElementById("next");

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  sliderWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
});

var prevSlide = function() {
  if(count > 1) {
    count = count - 2;
    slideList.style.left = "-" + count * sliderWidth + "px";
    count++;
  }
  else if(count = 1) {
    count = items - 1;
    slideList.style.left = "-" + count * sliderWidth + "px";
    count++;
  }
};

var nextSlide = function() {
  if(count < items) {
    slideList.style.left = "-" + count * sliderWidth + "px";
    count++;
  }
  else if(count = items) {
    slideList.style.left = "0px";
    count = 1;
  }
};

next.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nextSlide();
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
  prevSlide();
});

setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide()
}, 5000);

};

window.onload = function() {
responsiveSlider();  
}


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I increase the size, any tips are accepted. If it is impossible let me know so I stop trying.

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean, how do you increase size without ultimately using width and height? Do you mean how to avoid pixels and stretch by area length instead?

Comment: @alilland I am not sure if what I want is possible. I want the slideshow to be bigger basically.

Comment: you absolutely can make it bigger, just increase the width and height evenly

Comment: aaaah I got it to work, initially I tried that with the parent div but it didnt work because the photos were rendered in as small. I had to change the photo sizes and it worked, thanks @alilland

Comment: You might look into `object-fit`.  I've had success with putting this tag on `img` tags to get them to autosize.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

With the overflow, you have to increase the width and height of both the container AND the photos for it to work. Make sure to increase width and height evenly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).